How is 雰囲気 used in this sentence?
人の話なんてろくに聞かさない　雰囲気と勢いで周りを巻き込んで引っ張っていく人だ
The character is describing a personality type. While I'm famous with 勢いで akin to "with impetus" I'm not familiar with 雰囲気と here. What kind of nuance does it carry? "With the impetus and atmosphere"?

雰囲気 in this context essentially functions as an antonym to logic or reason. 雰囲気で話す人 describes someone who primarily relies on facial expressions, subjective impressions, or "vibes" when communicating. A person skilled at this style of communication may be viewed as charismatic when described positively, but would be considered illogical in academic settings.
